# Text won't appear in interface?

Tags: interface

There is one problem, it seems that text won't appear on my program. The three images show the errors and also my laptop specs (I believe I just have very small amount of laptop power that makes Blender glitch).

Everything else works fine (zooming, panning, rotating, etc.) and the buttons are still there and do what they're supposed to do, but the text just won't appear.

Might anybody know how to fix this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

The drive update didn't help either. I know a way around it though, does anybody know a page which shows screenshots of more or less the buttons on blender

Comment: Sometimes I see that when my RAM is nearly all used. Closing forgotten Firefox tabs and whatever other junk is up restores Blender to normal.

Comment: Can you show a picture of what comes up when you add a text?

Answer (score 4):

Here are some more links with almost identical issue:
[Blender Artist thread 1](http://www.elysiun.com/forum/showthread.php?334195-Blender-2-70-interface-no-text!!!!!) 
[Blender Artist thread 2](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?267185-Blender-interface-has-no-text-on-my-Notebook!!) 
[Blender Bug Tracker](https://developer.blender.org/T32717) 
Looks like you are running blender on a potato and there is no fix. This integrated graphics card will just not do. It shares the system RAM as a video-memory and when your system uses a lot (2GB is almost nothing) there is not enough left.
Check the minimal system specs:
[Minimal Blender Specs](http://www.blender.org/download/requirements/)

Comment: If it's a RAM shortage issue then it should be fixable by adding more memory.

Comment: It might be non-compatible gpu, drivers, memory or combination of it.