# There is nothing in header!

Tags: error

[image]

I've already deleted and redownloaded it for more than 10 times, but everytime my UI is like this! I could not find any solution from Google. I need 2.70 ver.! I tried to download 2.79 ver instead of that, but it dosen't have anything in header like this too!

Comment: Could you tell us what operating system you are using? and perhaps check for strange characters in any of the directory paths involved (which depend on the OS...)

Comment: Apart from what reported [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82130/the-info-bar-on-top-disappeared-and-the-mouse-pointer-is-misaligned) in this case Blender UI isn't fully drawn (no buttons, dropdowns, lists etc) which seems to be related to the same as here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19582/text-wont-appear-in-interface - graphic drivers problem of some kind.