# My blender shows all writings cut off

Tags: interface

My blender used to work fine with my previous video driver which unfortunately do not remember,but now the writings on tools,bootom bar,... appears cut off.if any one can tell me which driver is fit for nvidia geforce 320 please help me.

[image]

Comment: Can you add a picture of your interface? Because I don't think it is a video card problem, I don't have video card in my machine then too it is working correctly!

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add images that might help us understand what the problem looks like. ( to learn how to post images [read this link:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491))

Comment: @Yash can you see the picture now?

Comment: No, theirs no picture

Comment: @Yash it keeps saying" something went wrong when trying to upload the image"

Comment: So do one thing upload it to any file hosting site like google drive and then link it here

Comment: @Yash  httrps:.//we.tl/t-BYZesSF1tm

Comment: Your link is incorrect, it should be https://we.tl/t-BYZesSF1tm

Comment: I have seen this first time how is this possible

Comment: Delete the whole blender folder which you unzipped or installed after downloading and try re-downloading it from https://www.blender.org/download/

Comment: Let me know if it works!

Comment: Hi. For future reference: http://take-a-screenshot.org/

Comment: @RayMairlot  okay

Comment: @RayMairlot and is there any solution you might have came up?

Comment: @Nahom If I, or anyone else, had a solution, they would add an answer in the answer box below.

Comment: @RayMairlot I'm new for stack exchange,so can you take a screenshot of the answer box and send it to me?

Comment: I suggest taking the [Tour](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour) and looking in the [Help Centre](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: When the interface is missing elements like this it likely an issue with the drivers for the graphics card. Possible duplicate of [text won't appear in interface](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19582/text-wont-appear-in-interface)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your UI might be zoomed in. Try just pinch-scaling it.

(I don't know how to do this with just a mouse, but there's probably a way.)