# Text on the interface doesn't show correctly on a virtual machine

Tags: interface

I'm really sorry if this topic has been discussed already but google didn't show the thread. :-( 
I have some trouble running Blender in virtual machine. It's Linux Mint 19.1. The fonts inside the settings menu are not drawn correctly. Maybe someone knows about this.

I would be really happy if there would be a solution to this.

Thanks in advance
Cheers
Joe

[image: Screeshot]

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19582/text-wont-appear-in-interface. This is a problem with graphics card used on your system. Maybe you could try enable/disable Font Antialising in User prefs bot I doubt it can really change anything. Either use Blender with opengl lib in its root directory (will work slowly) or change hardware.

Comment: Thanks. I'm running Blender in a Virtualbox Linux and maybe the emulated graphics hardware goes crazy. On a regular machine with the same Linux distribution it works well. I just want to have it in the VM because I'm working in there and it would be much more comfortable for not to have to switch all the time.

Comment: VirtualBox or alike won't virtualize your hardware graphic card, as far as I know you will need to run more in-depth virtual machine like Xen to pick up the graphic card and use it there. With VirtualBox likely the only solution is to [run Blender in graphic legacy mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/73014/1245)

Comment: Obviously it's related to the 3D acceleration checkbox in the VM settings. If I uncheck the 3D acceleration checkbox the text is shown fine. But VM is running pretty laggy of course. For instance Youtube video stutter tremendously